# Extract metadata_fields from table as well as data columns from bigquery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have to query a bigquery table where in the requirement is to fetch below fields:

a) Table metadata columns( 2 columns)

b) Data columns( 3 columns)

for example :

```
table_id ,   creation_time , col_id1 , col2_id2, col3_id3
tbl_20180424, 1524641477022,  1, 2, 3
tbl_20180524, 1524647897022,  11, 12, 13
```

I tried below query but it is not working:

```
SELECT
table_id,
creation_time,
year,
Week,
id1,
id2,
id3
FROM (
SELECT  
table_id,
TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time) AS creation_time,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CAST(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time) as DATE)) Year,
EXTRACT(WEEK FROM CAST(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time) as DATE)) Week
FROM `project.dataset.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
where table_id like 'tbl_%' )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH data AS (
  SELECT CONCAT('tbl_', _TABLE_SUFFIX) AS table_id, col_id1, col_id2, col_id3
  FROM `project.dataset.tbl_*`
), metadata AS (
  SELECT 
    table_id,
    TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time) AS creation_time,
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CAST(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time) AS DATE)) Year,
    EXTRACT(WEEK FROM CAST(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time) AS DATE)) Week
  FROM `project.dataset.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
  WHERE table_id LIKE 'tbl_%'
)
SELECT *
FROM metadata
JOIN data
USING(table_id)
```

if to apply to simplified example in your question - result will be

```
Row table_id        creation_time               Year    Week    col_id1 col_id2 col_id3  
1   tbl_20180424    2019-09-20 19:21:38.600 UTC 2019    37      1       2       3    
2   tbl_20180524    2019-09-20 19:22:00.676 UTC 2019    37      11      12      13
```

Comment: I already wrote the above join query in different format but it was giving me performance issues as it was running in 3 min and your query is running in like 23 sec . Can you help me understand the reason of performance issue with my query .

Comment: how I can do this w/o seeing your query? :o)

Comment: select year , Week, id1 , COUNT(DISTINCT id2) as col4
from (SELECT
table_id,
creation_time,
year,
Week,
id1,
id2,
id3
FROM `project.dataset.<tables>_*` ,
(
SELECT  
table_id,
TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time) AS creation_time,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CAST(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time) as DATE)) Year,
EXTRACT(WEEK FROM CAST(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time) as DATE)) Week
FROM `project.dataset.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
where table_id like 'tbl_%' ))
where col1 = 'some value'
GROUP by year , week , id1 
ORDER by col4 DESC)

Comment: @MikhailCan you explain the difference in both the queries

Comment: which two queries? i see only one query in my answer

Comment: oh, i got it - you mean difference between query in my answer and query in your comment - i will look into it when get extra time and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you are trying to select `id1`, `id2`, `id3` but they are not in your subquery.  Additionally, consider looking into `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` as follows:

```
with tables as (select table_name, creation_time from dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES),
    columns as (select table_name, column_name, ordinal_position from dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS)
select
  table_name,
  creation_time,
  EXTRACT(YEAR from creation_time) as Year,
  EXTRACT(WEEK from creation_time) as Week,
  column_name,
  ordinal_position
from tables
inner join columns using(table_name)
order by table_name, ordinal_position
```

This query provides an un-pivoted result set of all tables/columns in your dataset.